# В бд добавляется 2 записи

Tags: php, mysql

когда нажимаю на insert в бд добавляется 2 записи с одинаковым goods_name, последующим goods_id.

поле goods_id autoincrement, integer, primary key.

goods_name типа varchar(100)

**Index.html**

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Hello Word</title>
 </head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

<body>
  <div id="head">
  <img src="images/alphasoft.png" alt="picture" height="60px">
  </div>    
  <div id="nav">
      <ul class="nav_main_ul">
        <li><a href="">Main</a>
          <ul class="submenu"> 
            <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="sidebar">

  </div>    
  <div id="content">
    <br />

    <form action="goods.php" method="post" style="margin-left:20px;"> 
    <h3>name</h3><br />
    <input type="text" name="goods"<br/> 
    <input type="submit" name="btn_select" value="select">
    <input type="submit" name="btn_insert" value="insert">
    </form> 
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>

 <?php
 include "connect_db.php";
 ?>

 </body>
</html>
```

**Connect_db.php**

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="edelin_user1";
$password="mariamiko159";

$db_name="edelin_mydb";

$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db_name) or die(mysqli_error() ); 


if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

**goods.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // настраиваем уровень ошибок
ini_set('display_errors', true); // включаем вывод ошибок на экран

include "connect_db.php";


////////////////select///////////////
if (isset($_POST['btn_select'])) {
 $sql="select * from goods";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

  echo "<table border='1' width='50%'>
  <tr>
  <th>Goods_id</th>
  <th>Goods_name</th>
  </tr>";


 //  Выводим данные каждой строки
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
   {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$row["goods_id"]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row["goods_name"]."</td>"; 
      echo "</tr>";
   }
 echo "</table>";
 mysqli_close($conn);
}

////////////////insert///////////////

if (isset($_POST['btn_insert'])) {
 $goods_name=$_POST['goods'];   

$sql="INSERT into goods(goods_id, goods_name) VALUES(NULL,'$goods_name')";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

 if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
} 



//header(string "Location:index.php");

?>
```

Comment: Но у вас же прямо один за одним идут два выполнения insert `$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))`

Comment: @Mike Да, действительно. Вы правы. Убрал $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) и правильно заработал. Не знал что if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) снова добавлял запись. Я думал он проверял истинность добавления предыдущим оператором($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);)
Спасибо!